# Is there a way to bypass the MS-DOS(FAT32) drive format to copy large files without reformatting?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file-management, format

On OSX, I'm trying to copy a 7GB file to an external drive whose format is `MS-DOS(FAT32)`, and am getting the

```
Can't be copied because it is too large for the volume's format.
```

message.

According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4263857?tstart=0, I have to reformat this drive to `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`, since the current format won't let me copy bigger files.

But I'd rather not. I have a Windows machine too and I use the drive with it as well, so I like this format. Besides, I have an absurdly large amount of other files in this drive, and I'd prefer not to do any backups at the moment.

Is there *any* other way to bypass this? I have tried splicing the file into several .RAR files (100MB each), and then uncompressing them all inside the drive. But this doesn't work (I imagine that the decompressing software needs to create a 7GB buffer file at some point...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAT32 is limited to 4GB file sizesd.  However, you said you have a Windows machine.  You can use the `convert.exe` command to convert the FAT32 to NTFS which your Mac can read and write to, as well as your Windows machine.

On your Windows machine, attach the external drive.  Then, from an administrative command prompt type the following and replace `drive_letter` with the appropriate drive letter.

> convert drive_letter: /fs:ntfs

This is non-destructive and you will not lose data.  Backups, arent necessary, but definitely preferred (just in case).  You can read more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456984.aspx).

Comment: Out of the box, OS X cannot write to NTFS.  You either need to do an unsupported hack or need third-party software. ExFAT is the supported option for Windows Vista and later.

Comment: @AlanShutko OSX absolutely supports NTFS.  http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588773-263/how-to-manually-enable-ntfs-read-and-write-in-os-x/

Comment: Yes, that is an unsupported hack.  Apple does not guarantee it will work, it is not on by default, and you may experience problems doing it.

Comment: Can I convert it back to FAT32 later? If yes, would the large file still exist (and be accessible) or would it cause problems?

Comment: no, its one way

Comment: Apparently the drive was damaged or something (it didn't work), but I ended giving up and reformatted the drive. Sadly I won't be able to use it with Mac I guess.

Comment: You can convert it ti exFAT for copatibility with both Mac and Windows, as well as 4GB+ file support.